# Capybara & RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

I can't make Capybara to work successfully, it complains that `has_text` is an undefined method.

I have created a new rails 3.1 project (`rails new test -T`).

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

I have installed the spec folder: `rails g rspec:install`.

spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

And finally my test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "the test" do
  scenario "GET /" do
    visit('/')
    page.should have_text('Welcome aboard')
  end
end
```

So I launch rspec: `bundle exec rspec spec/my_test.rb` and this is the error:

```
F

Failures:

  1) the test GET /
     Failure/Error: page.should have_text('Welcome aboard')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_text?' for #<Capybara::Session>
     # ./spec/my_test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: KL-7, what did you change in my question? I see it exactly as it was when I wrote it. In fact, I have made a diff of the two versions and they are identical.

Comment: Don't worry, nothing special. Just wrapped 'has_text' in the first sentence with backticks so it became a bit more noticeable. You can see it in revisions history.

Comment: Ok. Where is the revision history? (just to know, because I haven't found that option yet).

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you're using capybara `1.1.2` that is the current stable version, but it doesn't have `has_text?` method. You can either use [`has_content?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/1.1.2/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_content%3F-instance_method) (and corresponding `have_content` matcher) instead or use capybara directly from github repository as Skydreamer suggested.

Note that `has_content?` has a bit different behaviour as described in `README`. On the other hand using gem directly from repository is not always safe as this version might be not very stable.